# Upgrade VirtualBox headless 4.2 to 5.0 on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, upgrade, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox headless installation up and running on a Ubuntu Server 14.04 machine. I installed VirtualBox via `apt-get install virtualbox`. Now I would like to upgrade this installation to 5.0, and I have seen that it is available via `apt-get install virtualbox-5.0`.

Taking into account other related questions in this site, I see that I have to remove my current VirtualBox installation first, but I would like to know if it is possible to upgrade VirtualBox in one step so I wouldn't need to start from scratch registering and setting up all my virtual machines.

Comment: It's probably not impossible, if you have the skills to figure out how.

Comment: After installing a newer release settings of all your VMs will be kept. Except of guest additions no need to set it all up again.

Comment: @Takkat Thanks for your guidance! As you can see in my answer, I followed your advice and finally I managed to do the upgrade with not much effort

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have managed to set up virtualbox 5.0 up and running with all my virtual machines. I uninstalled virtualbox 4.0 using `apt-get remove` instead of `apt-get purge`, and `apt-get install virtualbox-5.0` kept all virtual machines registered. The only problem was that RPD connections weren't available in my headless installation because I didn't upgrade the VirtualBox extension pack. I noticed the problem after checking current extension packs by doing `vboxmanage list extpacks`, and replacing the old extension pack with the latest one. To wrap up, in case it can help to others these were the steps I followed:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox*
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
sudo vboxmanage list extpacks
sudo vboxmanage extpack install --replace 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' <new Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack file>
```